# Posting JSON to WebAPI - the JSON object includes an image (bytes) - Getting error: An expression is too long or complex to compile

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I'll start off saying I'm not very familiar with JSON.

I'm creating a web service that will accept JSON data from an iOS device, and takes that data and inserts it into a database.

The trouble I'm running into is that the image byte data is HUGE.  This is causing the server-side error "An expression is too long or complex to compile."

Here's the JSON data and JavaScript AJAX call:

```
var source = {
    "longitude": 96.84610000000001,
    "latitude": 35.5608,
    "username": "blah",
    "imageDataBlob": "\/9j\/4UI5RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAKAA8BAgASAAAAhgAAABABAgALAAAAmAAA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\nAAAAAAAAA6QDAAEAAAAAAAAABKQFAAEAAAAAAwAABaQDAAEAAAA...etc"
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/api/blah/PostPicture/",
    data: source
});
```

If I need to work with JSON data being passed to my web service, how can I work with such huge JSON objects?  Are there any configuration settings I can modify in my web.config to allow this?

Comment: *"An expression is too long or complex to compile."* I am guessing that is a serverside error on the .NET side?

Comment: Yes, it is a server side error.

Comment: And what JSON lib are you using to convert it over?

Answer (score 0):

Once we solved a similar issue by dividing the long string into several parts, something like imgBlob1,imgBlob2,imgBlob3,..and so on. Then on the server side join all those values to get back the big string again. You may want to give it a try.